# Can I to make sure that the key of one object is subset of keys of another object?

Tags: typescript

```js
export const masterKeysObject = {
    MAIN: 'main',
    REDIRECT: 'redirect',
    DASHBOARD: 'dashboard',
    USER_ID_PARAM: ':userId',
    CREATE_NEW: 'create_new'
} as const;

type MasterKeys = keyof typeof masterKeyObjects;

const allowedKeys: (keyof typeof masterKeysObjects)[] = [
    'DASHBOARD',
    'CREATE_NEW',
    // Add other allowed keys as needed
];

export const onlyAllowedKeysObject: Record<typeof allowedKeys[number], string> = {
    DASHBOARD: 'Dashboard',
    CREATE_NEW: 'Create New',
};
```

This does not work.

I get error

```js
Type '{ DASHBOARD: string CREATE_NEW: string;}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<"MAIN" | "REDIRECT" | "DASHBOARD" | "USER_ID_PARAM" | "CREATE_NEW", string>': ROOT, DEFAULT_REDIRECT, USER_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, and 2 more.ts(
```

Can I write TypeScript to make sure that the key of `onlyAllowedKeysObject` is a subset of `masterKeysObject` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type which declares all properties of an object as *optional* and thus allows you to assign a subset to an object type.

```
export const onlyAllowedKeysObject: Partial<Record<typeof allowedKeys[number], string>> = {
    DASHBOARD: 'Dashboard',
    CREATE_NEW: 'Create New',
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wEoQK42KuAXjgG8AoOOAWQEEBJAOQC44AiAWwEMBLZVgGgpwMAUQAidUQGEAKi1ZRgAE26KEMAULE0AygAkAQgHkaGMfKWdUACwBGETlCWbKAVR0iMAfTpivABVMaKnkmbFRgKDpnQUopURoZES8GEQB1eQRFTjwvZGAAd00AXzgrRBR0AG4yMiQ0eE4AGyaIAuUAaWAAT1QWAAoAax6IADM4GG6wYDHhHDxUAEoAbQBdIjhloVZtfWNTMRc2eJFE5NS0o4B6K7gaJSU4CBhrSLKWtuU4Yd6ygnzlMoyKsamRQJBYBUGk9kE1ujQPu0lF1ekZbAArYDqFj%20RwwbjNAA8QgwWOgSkJ-Um01mzVaSJRS2WyGw7FskVW-Dg6CgvAA5gA%20MgCjbkSi7QwmMzyMRWOwOJxHE5nFLpeRSbJ4OAMQolGpAA)

Comment: I need to ensure that no keys other than, the ones in `masterKeysObject` is allowed in `onlyAllowedKeysObject `

Comment: You still may only specify known properties. Try the playground link ;)